# Generalize airplane problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The well-known airplane problem is can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1029965/a-difficult-probability-question-about-choosing-seats).
I restated the problem below.

> $100$ women board a plane with $100$ seats. Each of them has a seat assigned in advance. For some reason the first woman who gets in takes a seat randomly. Then the second passenger takes her allocated seat if it is not occupied (by the first passenger), or picks a seat randomly if her own seat is occupied. The third passenger takes her own if not occupied by one of the first two ladies, or a random seat if it is.. and so on.

I would like to generalize the problem to $m$ passengers and $n$ misplaced passengers with $n\leq m.$
The problem above is when $m=100$ and $n=1$.

More precisely,

> Given $m$ passengers preparing to board a plane with $m$ seats, if there are $n$ passengers which may not follow their seats, then what is the probability that the last passenger can get their seat?

For the new question, I have no idea how to start at all.

Comment: Have you done some calculations with small $m$?  Or considered the case $n = m-1$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Probability of Sitting in Correct Seat](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2927930/probability-of-sitting-in-correct-seat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same argument works.  We only care about the order the seats for the misplaced passengers and the last passenger are filled.  All permutations are equally likely. 
 The chance the last passenger's seat is the last of these is $\frac 1{n+1}$.

Comment: When $n=1,$ your suggestion leads to probability $1$, where the true probability is $\frac{1}{2}.$ Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: You are correct.  I forgot to add in the last passenger.